# React-native Android build error in macOS Monterey

Tags: ios, macos

I recently updated to macOS Monterey. but suddenly it is not working.
(onlyA android build is not working.. iOS is OK)

the command is 'npm run android' (react-native run-android).

the error message is..

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/byun/Desktop/program/github/dadokdadok/app/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 395

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:copyDebugBundledJs'.
   > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
      > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

I don't know why.. please tell me..

Comment: I need an answer for this too.